# ng-model between two text box should work based on checkbox input

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am building an UI page, the form consists of 2 textbox and a checkbox, if the checkbox is true the content of both textbox should be updated to each other immediately.

Code sample
"

```
Registration number :

<input type="text" name="usr" id="usr" style="width:200px" value="{{usr}}" required="required"> <br>

Moodle Password :

<input type="password" name="pwd" ng-model="pwd2" value="{{pwd}}" id="pwd" style="width:200px"> <br>

Ffcs Password :

<input type="password" name="ffcs_pwd" ng-model="ffcs_pwd2" value="{{ffcs_pwd}}" id="ffcs_pwd" style="width:200px">
<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="same" id="same" unchecked> 
 Same password for both 
 <br>

<input type="submit" value="Log In">
```

"

Comment: Share your code please

Comment: can you explain more ? or can you please provide your code here.

Comment: Awesome, go build it. Come back if you run into problems.

Answer (score 0):

Keep ng-model for both password as different as in code below. Use checkbox value if it is true then you can give moodle password value to fcfs password like

```
Registration number : <input type="text" ng-model="regno"/>
Moodle Password : <input type="text" ng-model="modpass"/>
Ffcs Password : <input type="text" ng-model="fcfs"/>
Same password for both : <input type="checkbox" ng-model="chkbox"/>

if($scope.chkbox){
    $scope.fcfs = $scope.modpass
}
```

Or you can use $watch on Moodle password model.